# Wer kann "verklagen"

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Mir hatte mal jemand erklärt, dass folgende Formulierung sprachlich/fachlich falsch sei:

> Mickey verklagt Dagobert zu drei Jahren Haft.

Begründung war, dass nur der Richter verklagen könne. Es müsse daher heißen

> Mickey klagt gegen Dagobert und dieser wird zu drei Jahren Haft
>   verurteilt.

Leider fand ich dazu noch keine Quelle zur korrekten Verwendung des Wortes "verklagen". Wie ist die Definition und wo finde ich sie genau?
In der Presse wird dagegen oft (vermutlich umgangssprachlich, weil es kürzer ist)

> x verklagt y

geschrieben.

Comment: Der Richter verklagt nicht, er (ver)urteilt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Du kannst problemlos "jemanden verklagen", ohne dass es sprachlich oder fachlich falsch wäre. Du kannst es auch noch konkretisieren, zum Beispiel "jemanden auf Schadensersatz verklagen" oder "jemanden wegen Rufschädigung verklagen".

Mit "auf etw. verklagen" kannst du also ausdrücken, was denn das Ziel der Klage ist. In der Regel verklagt man aber "auf etwas", woraus man selbst profitiert. Schmerzensgeld, Löschung von Daten, Unterhalt, … Ich habe noch nie gehört, dass jemand "auf Inhaftierung verklagt" wurde.

Was nicht möglich ist, ist jemanden mit der Klage direkt zu verurteilen. Das musst du dann doch dem Richter überlassen, zu entscheiden, ob einer Anklage auch eine Verurteilung folgt. Sprich "zu etwas verklagen" macht logisch und auch fachlich keinen Sinn.

Praxisbeispiele (Hervorhebung made by me):

> Drei Monate später verklagte sie ihn **auf Anerkennung der Vaterschaft** und ging an die Öffentlichkeit. <sup>[zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/sport/2013-03/brasilien-bruno-mord-urteil)</sup>
>
> Er hatte den Flughafen sogar **wegen der Verspätung** am Bau verklagt. <sup>[zeit.de](http://www.zeit.de/wirtschaft/2013-03/flughafen-ber-hartmut-mehdorn)</sup>

---

Hinweis: Ob du rechtlich dazu befugt bist, eine Anklage einzureichen, ist dann noch mal eine andere Sache. Diese Frage kann dir ein Jurist mit Sicherheit beantworten, wobei ich befürchte, dass es noch abhängig davon ist, bei welchem Gericht du eine Klage einreichst. Vor manchen Gerichten brauchst du zum Beispiel zwingend einen Anwalt, bei anderen nicht.
Für eine Thematisierung dessen ist aber diese Seite nicht die richtige Wahl.

Meine Antwort bezieht sich daher auf den Standpunkt, dass Mickey – oder wer auch immer – die Befugnis hat, eine Anklage einzureichen.

---

Ergänzung:

Ich habe noch mal eingehender gesucht und keine Quelle gefunden, wo die Verben *verklagen*, *anklagen* etc. semantisch mit *Haftstrafe* oder gar deren Länge verbunden werden. Gängiger ist die Aussage, dass ein "Haftbefehl beantragt" wurde und dass eine Haftstrafe im Schlussplädoyer gefordert wird:

> Am vergangenen Freitag hatte die Staatsanwaltschaft *in ihrem Schlussplädoyer* eine **zweijährige Haftstrafe** für Fuentes **gefordert**. <sup>[sport1.de](http://www.sport1.de/de/fussball/fus_international/fussball_international_primera_division/newspage_692173.html)</sup>

Im Kontext eines Gerichtsprozesses gibt es eine *Anklage*, mehrere *Anträge* und letztlich eine *Verurteilung* oder eine *Freisprechung*. Man sollte die verschiedenen Aspekte nicht durcheinander werfen.

Und die kurze Aussage "x verklagt y" ist keine Umgangssprache. Es fehlen einfach nur weitere Informationen. In der Schlagzeile oder in der zweiten Überschrift wird diese Information gerne ausgelassen. Der Kürze wegen. Der Grund und was gefordert wird, steht dann im Text.

Comment: Ein hilfreiches Nachschlagewerk ist hier wieder das DWDS (Digitales Wörterbuch der deutschen Sprache). http://www.dwds.de/?qu=verklagen&submit_button=Suche&view=1

Comment: @TehMacDawg Ich verwende dafür oft das [Wortschatz-Portal der Uni Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/)

Comment: Zur rechtlichen Seite: Im deutschen Strafrecht gibt es zwar eine Klage (oder technisch genauer: "[Anklage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anklage)"), aber die wird von der Staatsanwaltschaft (StA) erhoben. Der Geschädigte kann nur eine [Anzeige](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strafanzeige) stellen, also die StA auf eine mutmaßliche Straftat hinweisen. Die StA prüft und entscheidet dann eigenständig, ob und wie verfahren wird. Nur in bestimmten Fällen kann auch der Geschädigte selber klagen ([Privatklage](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Privatklage)).